# Duplicate all Column Cell Input Values with first Column Cell input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an html table that is wrapped by a form with each cell having an input element in it.

I was wondering if there is a way to obtain the first cell's input value of a particular column and pasting that value in the rest of the cells in that column. In other words, the user will type into the input field of first cell and then click on button to duplicate that entry into the rest of the cells of that column.

Comment: It is possible.

Comment: Which part are you having difficulty with?  Building the HTML?  Getting a value from an input?  Setting cell text?

Comment: Creating the Javascript that would grab the input value of the first cell of column and then pasting it to all the other cells' input value of that same column. I just do not even know how to start on this one.

Comment: Normally you'd be suggested to have had a go first and show what you've tried, hence my question to try to narrow the problem down to something specific.  Not knowing where to start can be its own problem.

Comment: Yes, I guess I should have. I got as far as creating the onClick button/link and able to get value. Just did not know how to get the copied value pasted in the remaining column cells. So I thought I didn't have enough to merit posting. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a table with a button on each row, give the button a class so that it can have an event assigned:

```
<button type='button' class='copybtn'>copy</button>
```

don't use IDs as you need multiple buttons;

```
$(".copybtn").click(function() {
```

You can get the button's *column* using `var col = $(this).closest("td").index()` (add 1 as `.index()` is 0-based, but we need 1-based `:nth-child`).

Get the column cells using:

```
var cells = $("table").find("tr > td:nth-child(" + col + ")");
```

Various ways to handle this - eg get all the cells as above, then get the first for the input and last for the button or get the input from the first row's nth-child (as in the snippet)

To get the value: `var val = inp.val()`

To copy the values, depends on your HTML, you could give each destination cell a class then:

```
cells.find("td.dest").text(val);
```

or you can get all cells and exclude first/last:

```
tbl.find("tr:not(:first):not(:last) > td:nth-child(" + col + ")").text(val);
```

Altogether:

```js
$(".copybtn").click(function() {
  // get 0-based column index
  var col = $(this).closest("td").index() + 1;
  var tbl = $(this).closest("table");
  var val = tbl.find("tr:first td:nth-child(" + col + ")").find("input").val();
  tbl.find("tr:not(:first):not(:last) > td:nth-child(" + col + ")").text(val);
});
```

```css
input {
  width: 50px;
}

td {
  min-width: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='t'>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='text' class='inp' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' class='inp' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' class='inp' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button type='button' class='copybtn'>copy</button></td>
      <td><button type='button' class='copybtn'>copy</button></td>
      <td><button type='button' class='copybtn'>copy</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I was able to find examples of getting first cell in a ROW and pasting to the remaining cells of that ROW as your example above. But what I need and is harder to find answers to, is I need this same thing with Columns, not rows. First cell in a column copied and pasted to all the cells below it in that same column.

Comment: @James the key is `tr td:nth-child(col)` - updated answer

Comment: Thanks, I am working on it now. I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Was able to mimic above script. But two other challenges I tried to resolve before coming back. I have Column headings and all cells are input fields due to editing a MySQL database. So text needs to be input and we need to compensate for first row being column headings. Thanks.

Comment: Wanted to elaborate a little bit more on the headings ... My top row headings are using <th> which I thought would be overlooked since the script is looking for <td>.

Comment: Ok, well, you have an answer to your question.  The question was *very* limited in detail so we've had to try and guess what you wanted; if you'd even provided the HTML for the table would have been a start.  Normally, it would have been closed as too broad (and there's one vote for that), but you seemed like you needed some help *getting started*.

Comment: You should be able to change `$("table tr:first td")` to `$("table thead tr th")` or $("table tr:first > td")` to $("table tr:first > th") and `.text(xx)` to `.find("input").val(xx)`.  The question was about locating the column (`td:nth-child(col)`) anything else will be writing the code for you.  SO isn't about getting a final solution, it's about solving a specific problem (selecting cells in a column in this case) as this isn't a code writing service and any additional minor changes such as changing a `td` to a `th` you should be making using the answer here as a base.

Comment: Thanks, I don't mind putting the effort in the learning aspect. I actually love it. You have been a big help. I got it working the way I needed it too. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you'll need something like this:

```js
const copy=(id) => {
  var value = document.getElementById("col"+id+"-input").value
  var list = document.getElementsByClassName("col"+id+"-input")
  for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
    list[i].value = value
}

document.getElementById("col1-button").addEventListener("click", ()=>copy(1))
document.getElementById("col2-button").addEventListener("click", ()=>copy(2))
document.getElementById("col3-button").addEventListener("click", ()=>copy(3))
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="col1-input" class="col1-input"><button id="col1-button">OK</button><br>
      <td><input class="col1-input"></td>
      <td><input class="col1-input"></td>
      <td><input class="col1-input"></td>
      <td><input class="col1-input"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="col2-input" class="col2-input"><button id="col2-button">OK</button><br>
      <td><input class="col2-input"></td>
      <td><input class="col2-input"></td>
      <td><input class="col2-input"></td>
      <td><input class="col2-input"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="col3-input" class="col3-input"><button id="col3-button">OK</button><br>
      <td><input class="col3-input"></td>
      <td><input class="col3-input"></td>
      <td><input class="col3-input"></td>
      <td><input class="col3-input"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: See my response above to first answer. Not Rows but Columns. Thanks for taking time to respond though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...  JQuery solution.

Good luck!

```js
$(function() {
 
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    var inputVal = $(this).prev().val();
    
    // Plus one because arrays start at zero    
    var colIndex =  $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent()) + 1;
    
    $('table tr td:nth-child('+colIndex+')').not(':first')
      .html(inputVal);
    
  });
  
 
});
```

```css
body { margin: 10px; }
table { max-width: 600px; }
td { min-width: 280px; }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text"><button type="button">Copy</button></td>
      <td><input type="text"><button type="button">Copy</button></td>
      <td><input type="text"><button type="button">Copy</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: See my response above to first answer. Not Rows but Columns. Thanks for taking time to respond though.

Comment: Edited response.  Enjoy!  =)

Comment: Obviously I would suggest name-spacing the table and selector using a class.  Just so it doesn't mess with other tables.  Add a class to the table like class="my-calc-table-thing" the change the selector to $('.my-calc-table-thing tr td:nth-child('+colIndex+')').not(':first')
      .html(inputVal);